# Donating Blood on Chol Hamo'ed

Tags: medicine, melacha-creative-work, chol-hamoed, gifts, blood

I was asked to donate platelets this week because the local blood center is looking specifically for my blood type. The only practical time for me is over chol hamo'ed (as I am off from work). I have heard conflicting statements about whether it would be permissible to donate on chol hamo'ed. One side says that we avoid certain melachot on chol hamo'ed, including donating. I was told that the tzorech gufo, needs of my body, in this case, are not emergent or imminently time sensitive and I could schedule the donation for another time. But then I read a [quote](https://www.mdais.org/en/news-en/4320-mda-is-ready-to-welcome-passover) from the MDA in Israel,

> "In addition, MDA calls on the public to donate blood during Chol
>   Hamoed, due to the expected decline in blood donations during the
>   holiday period."

My shul's rabbi drew a distinction between the potential for a real shortage of blood in Israel over chol hamo'ed and the less severe concern in the U.S. but I am still wondering about the pre-emptive nature of the Israeli call vs. the "we are, right now, looking for your blood type" phone call I got.

I am not asking for a psak -- I have one. I am trying to understand how we determine the exigent circumstances (the [tzorech](https://www.ou.org/holidays/sukkot/hilchos-chol-hamoed/) [rabim](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Chol_HaMoed)) which could be balanced against the practices of Chol Hamo'ed.

The "Physical need" category applies (it seems) only to the self, not to what I could do to address the physical needs of another person so I need an algorithm by which to determine if other cases qualify as acceptable on Chol Hamo'ed or not. Said algorithm would have to take into account a variety of questions such as

-->Would there be any difference if I could (or would) not donate any other time?

-->Does it matter if the blood bank claims that there "might" be a specific recipient or an expected need? Must they provide proof?

-->If the need was determined to be strong enough to be allowed on Chol Hamo'ed (a tzorech but not [immediate](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/62553/1362) piku'ach nefesh) would it be strong enough to push aside the practice of not eating Kitniyot (note -- this is a real and practical question)?

Comment: In my experience, when they say they need O- specifically, that's not at all the same as when they say you matched a specific cancer patient with an unusual blood type

Comment: Can you explain what is the problem of melachot for giving blood.

Comment: @DoubleAA yes, but is it more than saying "we are holding a general drive"? Is there a line one can infer?

Comment: @kouty I can only take what I was told, " While we allow melacha for a tzorech haguf (I.e. Anything that needs to be done for someone who is sick or injured) we generally avoid scheduling those types of melachos on chol hamoed (I.e. Scheduling a physical at the doctor or a cleaning at the dentist). This would seem to fall into the same category" [excerpted from the email I received]

Comment: @rosends That's funny, because my Rav told me there's no problem to get a physical or dentist check over Chol HaMoed.

Comment: Your blood center says that they need your blood type. That means that they have, or foresee having, people who would need this blood - either to survive or to avoid medical damange and the threat of death. I'm no halakha specialist (I'm not observant nor even a believer) - but doesn't that count as effectively Pikuah Nefesh? That's much stronger than Tsorkhei Haguf or Tsorekh Rabin or those sorts of considerations.